# Snowflake : XML Parsing - How to parse the in-tags in xml content

Tags: xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are challenged by an XML content containing in-tags of http , which is causing snowflake to be unable to parse the content.

Example in the following xml content , we are unable to parse the xml content of the xpath component/header/contentMeta/titleGroup/title -

Because of the presence of in-tag - `<infoAsset>`

[image: xml content]

Please advise we need a way to extract complete content of the xpath - component/header/contentMeta/titleGroup/title

with the value as

> 

```
        <accessionId ref="info:x-wiley/casrn/108-80-5"></accessionId>
        <fc>S</fc>
        ‐Triazine‐2,4,6‐Triol
      </infoAsset>
      108‐80‐5
```

Comment: Can you paste a complete XML and exact desired result? I'm having trouble reproducing the problem

Comment: As @FelipeHoffa said, it is more helpful to post code as text instead of as an image.